# Could not prepare SQL statement

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, h2

I`m sending

> POST {"number":"111A111", "customer":"Customer Cuustomer Rrrr",
>   "phone":"1 800 5551212", "manager":"Manager Manager Manager",
>   "date":"2012-09-17", "curId":{"id":"1"}, "payments":[{"id":"1"},
>   {"name":"pomyit stekla"},{"price":"1000.0"}]}

and I get the 500 error:

> "Internal Server
>   Error","exception":"org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException","message":"org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException:
>   Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
>   not prepare statement; SQL [insert into bill_payments (bill_id,
>   payments_id) values (?, ?)];

Stacktrace:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "PAYMENTS_ID" not
>   found; SQL statement: insert into bill_payments (bill_id, payments_id)
>   values (?, ?) [42122-193]

Many to many relation in Bill class:

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = ru.test.practice.model.Payment.class)
public List<PaymentView> payments = new ArrayList<>();

public List<PaymentView> getPayments() {
    return payments;
}

public void setPayments(List<PaymentView> payments) {
    this.payments = payments;
}
```

Many to many relation in Payment class:

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = ru.test.practice.model.Bill.class, mappedBy = "curId")
private List<Bill> bills = new ArrayList<>();

public List<Bill> getBills() {
    return bills;
}

public void setBills(List<Bill> bills) {
    this.bills = bills;
}
```

I also have this field in a BillView class

```
public List<PaymentView> payments = new ArrayList<>();
```

SQL schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BILL_PAYMENTS (
  bill_id    INTEGER NOT NULL,
  payment_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE BILL_PAYMENTS
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (bill_id) REFERENCES BILL (id);
ALTER TABLE BILL_PAYMENTS
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (payment_id) REFERENCES PAYMENTS (id);
```

Comment: Your column is named `payment_id` you are referencing `payments_id` (notice the extra "s")

Comment: But I don`t have a reference to this column anywhere in code

Comment: Your attribute is named `payments` hibernate uses the name of your attributes to get the name of your columns. So you wi.l need to change the name of your attribute, change the name of the column or add an annotation to tell hibernate the name of the column in `payment_id`